# Where is the adapter pattern used in .NET?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, adapter

What areas of .NET did Microsoft leverage the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) in?  I am looking for specific examples of .NET components using Adapter.

Comment: Look the formal sample here http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would argue that the [`IDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.aspx) and related database access components follow the adapter pattern. This is because they provide a common interface, or wrapper, for very disparate APIs into RDBMS products.

Comment: @Oded Of course being very careful to make the distinction that **not all** interfaces are adapters.

Comment: This is inheritance, adapter is wraping object to make it look like other object

Comment: `IDbCommand` does wrap the other database components, in a sense. The connectors for MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. are each very different. The .NET team created this wrapper and others like it so that developers need only work with one set of methods and properties. As with many design patterns it's open to interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

What about [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)? Constructing it using `XmlSerializer(Type)` constructor creates XmlSerializer which would be like XML adapter for the given type. Then you can use `Serialize()`/`Deserialize()` methods to adapt to and from XML.